# How to plot a matrix with user-chosen parameters? R Shiny

Tags: r, plot, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I am trying to make a Shiny app that will plot gene of interest for a chosen patient. Each row is the gene name, and each column is a patient ID. For example:

```
        99901    99902  99903   99904
SKI     4.789    5.789  6.324   1.2222
VWA1    6.901    7.002  5.89    4.567
TTLL10  6.783    7.345  8.987   6.345

library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(lattice)

anno <- as.matrix(anno_genExp_gen3[1:3, 1:3])

#Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarPanel(
      titlePanel(title = "Gen3 Gene Expression Data"),
      selectInput(inputId = "patients", 
                  label = strong("Please choose patient/s to examine"),
                  choices = colnames(anno_genExp_off[,1:25]), 
                  multiple = TRUE),
      selectInput(inputId = "geneExp",
                  label = "Please select gene expressions/s to examine",
                  choices = rownames(anno_genExp_off[1:25,]), 
                  multiple = TRUE)),
    mainPanel(plotOutput("testPlot"))  
    )

server <- function(input, output) {
  pdata <- reactive(input$patients)
  gdata <-reactive(input$geneExp)
  output$testPlot <- renderPlot ({
    levelplot(anno, 
              col.regions=colorRampPalette(c("red","green","blue")))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The code above just plots a small matrix, but how do I get it to plot user inputs using reactivity?

If the user chooses `SKI` and `TTlLL10` only for patient `99901`, how will I go about plotting this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've myself created a sample dataframe as you mentioned above. Here's the modified code.

Changes i made:

- `input$geneExp` and `input$patients` are already reactive so there is no need to use a separate reactive function.
- Filtered the dataframe for plotting use the same
- Also, made a default `selected` value in the `selectInput` to avoid the initial error message when nothing is selected

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(lattice)

anno_genExp_off <- data.frame(`99901` = c(4.3,6.5,6.6),
                              `99902` = c(5.3,7.5,8.6),
                              `99903` = c(6.3,8.5,9.6),
                              row.names = c("SKI","VWA1","TTLL10"))


anno <- as.matrix(anno_genExp_off)

#Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    titlePanel(title = "Gen3 Gene Expression Data"),
    selectInput(inputId = "patients", 
                label = strong("Please choose patient/s to examine"),
                choices = colnames(anno_genExp_off), 
                selected = colnames(anno_genExp_off)[1],
                multiple = TRUE),
    selectInput(inputId = "geneExp",
                label = "Please select gene expressions/s to examine",
                choices = rownames(anno_genExp_off), 
                selected = rownames(anno_genExp_off)[1],
                multiple = TRUE)),
  mainPanel(plotOutput("testPlot"))  
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  #pdata <- reactive(input$patients)
  #gdata <-reactive(input$geneExp)


  output$testPlot <- renderPlot ({
    levelplot(x = as.matrix(anno_genExp_off[which(rownames(anno_genExp_off) %in% input$geneExp) ,input$patients]), 
              col.regions=colorRampPalette(c("red","green","blue")))
  })
}

shiny::shinyApp(ui,server)
```

[image]

Comment: I've just chosen a level plot as a practice plot, do you think there is a better way to visualise this data?

Comment: Sorry I couldn't think of any other than Mosaic Plot. Please mark this as an answered if this has solved the question. Also feel free to post another question for the visualization type, you might get better results.

Comment: You're a legend!! Solved the problem and thank you for the suggestion :D